# Does sorting a Java stream before calling allMatch with a predicate that has different costs gain any benefits?

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream

I have implemented a Java stream pipeline where some elements are sorted and checked if all of them fulfill a predicate. The pipeline looks like this:

```
items.stream()
     .sorted(this::sortByType)
     .allMatch(this::isCompliant);
```

The validation by the predicate differentiates in costs. Some of the elements just need to check an attribute, for some of them I have to fetch potentially many elements from a database and evaluate them, too.

As I need to know that **all** of them are true, knowing that **at least one** is false, is equivalent. If I correctly understand the JavaDoc of the allMatch() operation, it should short curcuit as soon as one element is false.

So, in order to potentially improve the execution speed, I order the elements so that all of the very easy validations are executed first and only if they all succeed, I execute the more costly validations.

That is at least what I think happens. However, my IDE tells me, that sorting before calling allMatch() is redundant, because it does not depend on the sort order.

I wrote some tests which seem to indicate that the sort order *is in fact* regarded when traversing the pipeline, but maybe my test case is just to small or it just happened to be called correctly.

So my question is: Does allMatch() consider the sort order imposed beforehand? Or does it ignore it?

Comment: I don't see where your IDE gets that idea. Nothing can possibly go into `allMatch()` until after the sort completes, so of course if depends on the sort order.

Comment: "Nothing can possibly go into allMatch() until after the sort completes" this isn't true. allMatch needs to check (up to) all elements, so the order it does that in isn't relevant for correctness of the result; and sorting doesn't add our remove elements; hence the sorting _could_ be optimized away.

Comment: @AndyTurner That doesn't make sense. Nothing can come *out* of the sort until it has seen all the elements in the stream: then the leastmost element becomes available to the next step in the pipeline.

Comment: @user207421 can you give an example where the ordering of a stream affects the value of an allMatch operation?

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you give me an example of a sort algorithm that can produce the leastmost element before it's seen all the input?

Comment: No, but that's not what we are doing here: we are checking if a predicate matches everything in the stream, not looking for the minimal element.

Comment: @AndyTurner 1. You claimed that 'nothing can go into the `allMatch()` until after the sort completes' is untrue. It isn't untrue, and you are now evading that issue. 2. The question is about performance. If the predicate is `x -> x > 10` and the sort produces a least element of `x == 1`, the `allMatch()` can fail immediately, instead of whenever `x == 1` turns up in the unsorted stream.

Comment: @user207421 no evasion here. I'm saying that `stream.sort(...).allMatch(...)` has the same result as `stream.allMatch(...)`, i.e. the sort can be elided without affecting the result. In the worst case, the first is O(n log n) + O(n) = O(n log n); the second is O(n). Therefore it is better performance (in the worst case).

Comment: @user207 There's nothing that stops the compiler/runtime from encoding certain information such as "if an operation that produces an unordered sequence is preceded by a sort then eliminate the sort". As a matter of fact other languages that implement something similar to the stream API do this for certain implementations and certain circumstances.

Comment: @AndyTurner from a pure complexy theory point of view, you are absolutely right. But the worst case is not the most likely case. To what my question may boil down: Does the stream *firstly* sort *everything* and than apply the predicate? Or does it "bypass" somehow?

Comment: @AndyTurner *Of course* it has the same *result:* but that's not the question. The question is about *performance.* If the sort can present a predicate-failing case sooner to `allMatch()`, that means that `allMatch()` gets called fewer times: and if the cost of the sort is less than the cost of whatever the `allMatch()` has to do over the entire stream, the OP is ahead.

Comment: @melix It sorts everything first.

Comment: @Voo There is nothing that gives either the compiler or the runtime system enough information to do any such thing, given that database operations are involved.

Comment: @user207421 your explanation is completely off, `sorted` does not do anything except storing the information that sorted processing has been requested and `allMatch` is only invoked a single time. It’s one operation and the implementation of that operation decides whether to perform the previous steps or skip them. For example, `count()` does already skip a preceding sorting step in some cases. This has been added in Java 9 though the possibility existed in Java 8 too. Likewise, an `allMatch` implementation of a future Java version may skip the sorting even if the current version does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description

> The validation by the predicate differentiates in costs. Some of the elements just need to check an attribute, for some of them I have to fetch potentially many elements from a database and evaluate them, too.

I created a simple test case. The class `Waiter` has a single `int` property that defines the sort order and also how long it takes to evaluate the predicate:

```
public class Waiter implements Comparable<Waiter> {
    private final int time;

    public Waiter(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return time > 10;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Waiter o) {
        return Integer.compare(time, o.time);
    }
}
```

The class `Sorter` creates a few `Waiter`s and outputs the time for `allMatch()` on either the unsorted or the sorted list of waiters:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var data = List.of(
                new Waiter(500),
                new Waiter(500),
                new Waiter(500),
                new Waiter(500),
                new Waiter(1)
        );
        System.out.printf("Duration sorted: %d ms%n", time(() -> data.stream().sorted().allMatch(Waiter::isValid)));
        System.out.printf("Duration unsorted: %d ms%n", time(() -> data.stream().allMatch(Waiter::isValid)));
        System.out.printf("Duration sorted: %d ms%n", time(() -> data.stream().sorted().allMatch(Waiter::isValid)));
        System.out.printf("Duration unsorted: %d ms%n", time(() -> data.stream().allMatch(Waiter::isValid)));
    }

    private static long time(Runnable r) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        r.run();
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }
}
```

And the result is as expected: if the `Waiter` that whos predicate evaluates to false is the first (i.e. the data is sorted) the `allMatch()` is evaluated faster:

> ```
> Duration sorted: 6 ms
> Duration unsorted: 2021 ms
> Duration sorted: 3 ms
> Duration unsorted: 2030 ms
> ```

Note that if I change the last `Waiter` to also wait 500ms the unsorted variant is always faster (because sorting takes time and doesn't change the output for the case where all predicates match)

---

Please remember that this is a very simplistic test and may be skewed by various factors:

- this is not a proper microbenchmark. There is no warmup and only a two runs of both tests. The numbers might look different after a proper warmup.
- sorting itself takes time. In this simple case the time to sort the data is small, but your data may differ

  - sorting pays off only if `allMatch()` can short-circuit (i.e. at least one predicate fails)
  - on the other hand, for the case where all predicates return true you **have a performance penalty** due to the sorting

---

Conclusion:

- sorting the stream offers benefits if some predicates fail and sorting has the effects that the predicates that fail are moved to the beginning of the sorted stream.
- for the case where all predicates match there is a penalty for the sorting

You need to find out which of those two cases better describes your problem.

Comment: This tests just one particular implementation. There is no guaranty that `allMatch` will respect the `sorted` request. You could build an ordered solution around `findFirst()` but even then, it’s not guaranteed that the processing order matches the encounter order.

Answer (score 1):

> Does `allMatch()` consider the sort order imposed beforehand? Or does it ignore it?

If you are asking ... does `allMatch()` have to wait until the stream contents are sorted, the answer is going to be yes, for a sensible implementation of `sorted()`<sup>1</sup>.

If you are asking if `allMatch()` *could* benefit from the stream being sorted, then the answer is yes, because of *possible* short-circuiting in `allMatch` when it encounters an element for which the predicate returns `false`.  (The javadocs don't say that short-circuiting *will* happpen<sup>2</sup>, but that would be a legitimate implementation approach.) But could also go the other way.  It depends ...

---

The question of whether it is more efficient to sort first will depend on the relative costs of `equals` vs `validate`, AND on the probability that elements will fail to validate.  There will be a point where you spend more time sorting than you will gain *on average* by reducing the `allMatch()` cost.

Unfortunately ... the mathematics of this will be complicated<sup>3</sup>, and will require accurate cost *functions* and probability distributions to provide an valid answer.

My advice would be make sure you are not doing premature optimization.  And when you do optimize, make sure that your trial datasets are representative.  My intuition says that the optimal algorithm is likely to be very data dependent, and that can makes optimization problematic.

---

But here's a thought.  Rather than sorting in ascending order of cost of validation, how about sorting in descending order of probability of validation failure?

---

<sup>1 - In theory, `sorted` could deliver the first (smallest) element in the stream in O(N).  However, optimizing it to do that would most likely be an anti-optimization overall.

2 - The javadoc says *"[may not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result."*.  It does not say **will not** or **shall not**.

3 - ... and way beyond my ability.</sup>

Comment: Interesting idea! But unfortunately, there is no way to know beforehand if any validations may fail.

Comment: I said *probability* ... not certainty.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: Does `allMatch()` consider the sort order imposed beforehand? Or does it ignore it?

I found no guarantees in the JavaDoc that `allMatch` will respect the encounter order. It *might* be implemented to respect the encounter order anyway.

Relevant sections of the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Ordering) are (emphasis mine):

> Streams may or may not have a defined encounter order. [...] Some intermediate operations, such as `sorted()`, may impose an encounter order on an otherwise unordered stream. Further, ***some terminal operations may ignore encounter order***, such as `forEach()`.

> If a stream is ordered, ***most*** operations are constrained to operate on the elements in their encounter order.

So `allMatch` could very well be implemented so that it does not process elements in the sorted order, similar to `findAny` and `forEach`. I can't think of a good reason why someone would implement it that way, but nevertheless, the documentation does not guarantee.

As always with performance, the best thing to do is to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Actually write benchmarks on some real data to see which one is faster. The performance depends on many more factors than just "does `allMatch` respect the order".

If you have a large number of `items`, for example, it might not be worth the effort to sort all of them, regardless of whether `allMatch` respects the order.

Comment: The “good reason why someone would implement it that way” is the same reason as to why `findAny` or `forEach` are specified as unordered: because sorting is not short-circuiting and can be expensive. Though, at the moment, `count()` is the only terminal operation actually skipping a sorting step in the reference implementation.